# First order approximation of integral curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is a smooth vector field so that $F(0)=0$ and $d_0F=A$, i.e.
$$F(x)=Ax+O(|x|^2)$$

Let $\phi_t:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be the one-parameter family of diffeomorphism generated by the integral curves of $F$. Is it true that

$$d_0\phi_t=e^{tA}$$

My intuition says it should be true, at least when the vector field is actually $F(x)=Ax$, we know that $\phi_t(x)=e^{tA}x$. But since I cannot write down $\phi_t$ explicitly, I cannot find its first order approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got an answer. Let $F(x)=\left(F^1(x),F^2(x),\cdots,F^n(x)\right)$ be a vector field. Then $A=\left(a_i^j\right)=\left(\partial_iF^j(0)\right)$ as a matrix. We want to show that
$$(d_0\phi_t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt}\left(d_0\phi_t\right)=A$$

Indeed, let $Y(x)=\left(Y^1(x),\cdots,Y^n(x)\right)$ be an arbitrary vector field, and write $Y_0=Y(0)$ then
$$\begin{align}
(d_0\phi_t)^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\left(d_0\phi_t\right)Y&=-\mathcal L_FY(0)\\
&=[Y,F](0)\\
&=Y_0\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(0)\;\;\;\;(\text{since $F(0)=0$})\\
&= AY_0
\end{align}$$

Since $Y$ is arbitrary and we are only checking it at the point $x=0$, we conclude that

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(d_0\phi_t\right)=\left(d_0\phi_t\right)A$$

Together with the fact that $d_0\phi_0=Id$, we conclude that

$$d_0\phi_t=e^{tA}$$